# How to animate UICollection View without scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uicollectionview, ios9

I have a collection view with this properties:

1. `collection.frame = CGRectMake(0,20,fullWidth,0)`
2. `collection.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100 , 0, 0, 0)`

I run this animation:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0,animations:{
                                let frame = CGRectMake(0, 20,fullWidth,200)
                                 collection.frame = frame
                      }completion: {})
```

the animation works perfect , but the problem is :

it appears that the collection scroll up automatically while the animation run !

so at the end of the animation the user should scroll up to see the first cell. How to solve that ? thanks

**EDIT**:
i solved this by changing contentOffset.y after the animation complete.

Comment: If you only wants to scroll to first cell then please add the below code in completion block:


`NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
  [collection scrollToItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];`

Comment: never animate the frame, animate the constraints instead !